# How to change the size of tableview programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I try to change the size (the width) of a table viewcontroller (the panel with text over syria):

[image]

I have tried :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 310, self.view.frame.size.width,200);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Do you know how can I reduce the width of the TableView ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: yes, of course           .

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the table view as a subview to your view controllers view with the new size in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

Check the view frame width to make sure it is actually less than 320 before setting it. Most likely you are setting the table view width back to 320 which is the entire width.

Also if you are just setting the width of the table I would recommend doing the following.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.width = 250;
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
}
```